# Embedded link in text or small link icon next to it in document?

Tags: icons, hyperlinks

In a document which has so many links (e.g. [this CV](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/cv.html)), where the blue is overwhelming the black, and the whole sentences/groups of words are links, not just some words in the middle, should we use a small link icon next to the text instead of embed it? Something like this:

> Three regularity results in harmonic analysis [image]

If this method is used, I don't know should we make both text and the icon clickable (not change the color of the text), or just the icon is clickable?

Answer (score 4):

No, because if you do that, then you will have lots of icons on the page and it may cause a detrimental amount of visual clutter on the screen. I seriously don't find any problem with the attached CV. However you can play with readability, try use zebra pattern style (aka swim-lanes) on the  table and add space around the content.

Answer (score 1):

Making just the icons clickable will less convenient to use. I would recommend against using the icons, blue underlined text is a clear identification of a hyperlink.  Icons will just look unnecessary elements

However, with little CSS or JS coding you can add the link image to see  how it looks.

Comment: Will it work in PDF format?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add icons and changing the color of a link to match the normal text is a bad idea as well.

Maybe you could simply add footnotes at the bottom?

Something like this...
http://codepen.io/run-time/pen/XJXGgB

Comment: My output is PDF format so I'm afraid that this preference is depend on which reader is used.

Comment: changed my answer to the footnote idea because I think it satisfies the conditions while being more clear than adding a bunch of icons